# VBA ClassModule in Excel doesn't recognise all methods (run-time error '438')

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom Class in Excel, and some of its methods are recognised while others aren't.

VBA returns the **run-time error '438' object doesn't support this property or method** once my module gets to **.addButton "button1", "Click Me", "msgbox (""Button clicked!"")"** but it has no issue with the previous line, which is a method of the same object.

What could be causing VBA to not recognise the addButton() method, when it recognises createForm() and successfully creates a UserForm?

Module (Example.bas)

```
Sub Example()

    Dim Form As New UserInterface                                           ' Match Type to UI class module name

    With Form
        .identifier = "example_form"                                        ' A unique identifier for the UserForm
        .title = "Example Window"                                           ' Window title
        .createForm                                                         ' Creates the UserForm
        .addButton "button1", "Click Me", "msgbox (""Button clicked!"")"    ' Adds a button UI element with title and method
        .renderForm                                                         ' Presents the UserForm, then deletes it when closed
    End With

End Sub
```

ClassModule (UserInterface.bas)

```
Private formIdentifier As String
Private formTitle As String

Public Property Let identifier(str As String)
    formIdentifier = str
End Property

Public Property Get identifier() As String
    identifier = formIdentifier
End Property

Public Property Let title(str As String)
    formTitle = str
End Property

Public Property Get title() As String
    title = formTitle
End Property

Public Function createForm()

    Set Form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

    With Form
        .Properties("Name") = formIdentifier
        .Properties("Caption") = formTitle
        .Properties("Width") = 500
        .Properties("Height") = 25
    End With
 
End Function

Public Function addButton(name As String, caption As String, code As String)

    Set Form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(formIdentifier)
    Set Button = Form.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
    
    With Button
        .Name = name
        .Caption = caption
        .Accelerator = "M"
        .Top = Form.Height
        .Left = 25
        .Width = 450
        .Height = 25
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    End With
    
    Form.Height = Form.Height + Button.Height + 25

    Form.codemodule.insertlines 7, "Private Sub " & name & "_Click()"
    Form.codemodule.insertlines 8, code
    Form.codemodule.insertlines 9, "End Sub"
 
End Function

Public Function renderForm()

    VBA.UserForms.Add(formIdentifier).Show
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(formIdentifier)
 
End Function
```

Comment: Change settings in VBE to stop at every error and you will see that the error is in the line `.Top = Form.Height`. I'd also recommend to use `Option Explcit`.

Comment: Great tip! Thank you so much. This solved the problem. For anyone who finds this: the correct way to get the height of a UserForm is Form.Properties("Height")

Comment: [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx) is a description of the possible settings,. In the case above it would possible have been sufficient to break only in class modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime error is not issued by the fact that the method `addButton` cannot be called. The method itself is raising a runtime error, but depending on your debugger settings, it will or will not stop at the line that causes the error as it is a method within a class (see comment of Storax).

The object `form` in your class is not of type `Userform`, it's of type `VBComponent`. This class has no property like `Height` that you can access to read and set the height of the form. It has, however, a Property named `Properties` which is a list of Properties that you can read and modify:

```
.Top = Form.Properties("Height")
(...)
form.Properties("Height") = form.Properties("Height") + Button.Height + 25
```